# Totalling elements in an arraylist

Tags: java

I'm trying to do the following:

A method that totals all of the cat’s legs in an ArrayList of cats.

However I can't seem to have it add up the total number of cat legs in the array, or display it on the console.

```
   public static int getNumOfLegs()
{

    return numOfLegs;
}

public void setNumOfLegs(int numOfLegs)
{
    this.numOfLegs = numOfLegs;

}



   public static int totalNumOfLegs(ArrayList<Cat> catList)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (Cat c: catList)
    {
        total = total + getNumOfLegs();
    }


    return total;

}
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: `return 4 * catList.size()` and if you're off because of an amputee cat, just call it experimental error. ;-)

Comment: so, is `numOfLegs` a static member? If it isn't how can you return it from the static method? And if it is, why are you setting its value via `this` in `setNumOfLegs()`

Answer (score 6):

Change:

```
total = total + getNumOfLegs();
```

To:

```
total = total + c.getNumOfLegs();
```

Comment: There are sadly supposed to be cat amputee's :(  Thank you both! How would I go about making it display to the console? I have System.out.println("The total number of dogs trained is: " + getNumOfLegs());                   but it doesn't work.

Comment: `System.out.println("The number is " + totalNumOfLegs(aListOfCats))`.  But it seems to me like you have made some more fundamental mistakes in your "design" here.  Like how come do you have a method for counting cat legs ... but you are trying to print out the number of dogs trained?

Comment: Ah yes that, I'm making a Dog program as well, same stuff in it really I just copied it from there, but it's correct now thank you. Now where do I put that System.out.println("The number is " + totalNumOfLegs(aListOfCats)) my array is called catList so I assume I replace that but it's giving me an error whenever I put this line :/ I'm just having the worst time with this script.

Answer (score 0):

assuming every cat has different number of legs - you will need to total each cat's legs individually. For this you need to use your cat object in your for loop (you named it c) to get the number of legs. (suggested already as c.getNumOfLegs();

Also, your static methods getNumOfLegs and setNumOfLegs should be in the class definition of Cat (and not static of course)